# ¿Hay alguna manera de que se pueda leer un Enter como salto de linea?

Tags: c++

Muy buenas, me encuentro estudiando C++ y estoy en un ejercicio sobre el manejo de archivos, el ejercicio establece que tengo que hacer que el programa reciba caracteres por parte del usuario a modo de strings formando párrafos, para posteriormente escribir ese párrafo en un archivo que el mismo programa creara.

Este es mi codigo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Texto
{
public:
  string text;
  string linea; 

  void userText()
  {
    do
    {
      getline(cin, linea);
      text += linea;
    } while (linea != "");
  }

  void to_string()
  {
    cout << "\n" << "User's Text: " << "\n" << text << "\n";    
  }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Texto& t)
{
  os << t.text;
  return os;
}

int main() {
  Texto prueba;
  prueba.userText();
  prueba.to_string();
  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

Con este código el usuario podrá seguir ingresando los caracteres en la consola hasta que este no escriba nada y presione enter, posteriormente el programa regresa lo que se escribió para ver si estaba bien, pero tengo el problema de que el texto lo escribe todo junto, y no se como poder implementar de que tome los enter del usuario y los tome como saltos de linea.
 Para que puedan aparecer de la siguiente forma:

"Hola como estas?

Bien y tu?"

Pero en su lugar, aparecen así:
"Hola como estas?Bien y tu?"

No he implementado el manejo de archivos, ya que quiero que el texto salga bien para poder implementarlo a los archivos, ya que el manejo de estos no es algo que me de muchos problemas.
Espero me puedan ayudar, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Sin ver tu código, es bastante difícil ayudarte. ¿ Podrías mostrar un [mcve] ?

Comment: Listo, ya pase el código, una disculpa, aun no me familiarizo del todo con el funcionamiento del sitio y de como escribir el código.

Answer (score 2):

Tu función userText modificala asi. Espero te ayude. Un saludo

```
void userText()
  {
    do
    {
      getline(cin, linea);
      text +=linea+"\n";
    } while (linea != "");
  }
```

Comment: Sí, con eso quedo, no se como no se me ocurrio XD.  Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Si te he entendido bien, tu problema está aquí:

```
text += linea;
```

¿ Porqué eso es un problema ? Pues muy sencillo: `getline( )` **elimina** el salto de línea de los datos de entrada. A ti te entrega una cadena **sin** el `'\n'`. Tu lo estás almacenando **todo junto**, **sin separaciones**.

Pues ya está, basta con añadir ese `'\n'` a tu texto:

```
text += linea;
text += '\n';
```